# Cómo saber que la instalación de recaptcha v3 es correcta

Tags: recaptcha

he instalado  recaptcha v3 guiándome a través de este tutorial
https://netbulbsocialmedia.com/noticias/tutorial-para-configurar-google-recaptcha-v3-ejemplo-en-php/
Lo he instalado y me aparece al fondo a la derecho derecho un ícono de Google reCAPTCHA:
Pero yo mi pregunta es ¿que métodos puedo emplear para saber si funciona correctamente? aparecer, aparece, pero no se si todo esta correcto.
Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de tus necesidades, la respuesta oficial es que lo puedes usar en cualquier caso de uso donde sea necesario validar la interacción del usuario (el uso más común en es el login), una vez que ya tienes la medalla de reCaptcha toca invocar la API de Google para obtener el score de la interacción del usuario.

Te recomiendo leer [este apartado](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#interpreting_the_score) en la documentación oficial donde menciona la interpretación del score y algunos casos de uso donde se recomienda el uso de reCaptcha.

Comment: Si ahora lo entiendo en la consola se puede ver las solicitudes que hay y las que pueden ser sospechosas. No sabía que hay una consola al respecto.La verdad que aunque son diferentes apartados pero resulta muy útil como la consola de Webmasters Tools de Google. Estaba un poco perdido de como saber como actuaba el captcha. Muchas gracias por la info.